# How to know if sets in $\mathbb{R}$ that have $\infty$ are opened or closed

Tags: general-topology

I was left with some examples of sets to determine if they are closed or opened. Two of these sets have $\infty$:

1) A={1/n} from n=1 to $\infty$

What I understand from this is that this set goes from 1 and converges to 0, so this set is closed.

2) A=(0,$\infty$)

But in this example there is always a ball for each point since the set goes to infinity and there is always another point in $\mathbb{R}$. Is this the case? or does it converge to some number and makes this set an open-closed set?

How do I interpret $\infty$ in $\mathbb{R}$ for this type of cases.

Comment: $(0,\infty) =\{ x\in\Bbb R\,|\, x>0\}$, infinity symbol is just used to denote unboundedness. For the first one, how do you exactly conclude that the set is closed? You claim that you found a sequence in $A$ that converges to $0$ (which is correct), so why is $A$ closed? For the second one, your argument is correct.

Comment: The first one is neither open nor closed. It isn't open because we have an isolated point at $n=1$. It isn't closed because it's complement $S$ contains $0$ but $(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$ isn't a subset of $S$ for any $\epsilon$. The second one is open trivially.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122, depends on how exactly you define topology. If you do it from the Euclidean metric, it needs proving in the manner that OP did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set of members of a convergent sequence is not necessarily a closed set. $S=\{1/n: n\in \mathbb N\}$ is not closed because $0$ is a limit point of $S$ that does not belong to $S.$

The set $T=(0,\infty)$ is open because for $x\in T,$  the open ball centered at $x$ with radius $x/2$ is a subset of $T.$ $T$ is not closed because $0$ is a limit point of $T$ that does not belong to $T.$

The only subsets of $\mathbb R $ that are both open and closed are the empty set and $\mathbb R.$

$T$ does not converge to anything because $T$ is not a sequence. A sequence is a function $f$ whose domain is $\mathbb N.$  We say "the sequence $(f(n))_{n\in \mathbb N}$" rather than "the sequence $f$" for clarity of thought.

Within the real numbers, $\infty$ is often used as an abbreviation for a phrase.
There is no number $\infty$ in $\mathbb R.$ It is sometimes useful to augment the set of reals to the set $\mathbb R\cup   \{\infty\}$ but many of the usual rules of arithmetic do not apply to the point $\infty.$

Answer (score 0):

Both questions use $\infty$ as a notational device, and in different ways.

The former uses it in the definition of a sequence of elements of $\mathbb{R}$. It is merely used in the index, and has nothing to do really with the actual elements $a_n$

The latter just signifies that the set of reals $(0,\infty)$ is unbounded above. In neither case is $\infty$ a de facto  point in the space.